# Reindexing issue due to weee product attribute created via program

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

Due to the newly created attribute(via program) of the type "weee", getting an error in reindexing.

```
Catalog Search indexer process unknown error:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.custom_attr_weee' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`custom_attr_weee`, `e`.`sku` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_website` AS `website` ON website.product_id = e.entity_id AND website.website_id = 1
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `visibility_default` ON visibility_default.entity_id= e.entity_id AND visibility_default.attribute_id = '99' AND visibility_default.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `visibility_store` ON visibility_store.entity_id= e.entity_id AND visibility_store.attribute_id = '99' AND visibility_store.store_id = 1
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `status_default` ON status_default.entity_id= e.entity_id AND status_default.attribute_id = '97' AND status_default.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `status_store` ON status_store.entity_id= e.entity_id AND status_store.attribute_id = '97' AND status_store.store_id = 1 WHERE (IF(visibility_store.value_id > 0, visibility_store.value, visibility_default.value) IN (3, 2, 4)) AND (IF(status_store.value_id > 0, status_store.value, status_default.value) IN (1)) AND (e.entity_id > 0) AND (e.entity_id
```

If we create this attribute via the admin panel, everything works fine. What might be the issue? Help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

When an attribute is created via admin panel or 3rd program, it must be stored in `eav_attribute` tablee. In your case, the program added `weee` attribute directly into `catalog_product_entity table`, it's forbidden and causes this error.